# Compare values in a single array and return the key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

`$age=array("Peter"=>43,"Ben"=>67);` .

The array contains only two key value pairs. First i need to check if the values of these two keys are same. If same then it returns the key of these two value, otherwise return false. So here value 43 and 67 are not same so it should return false. If the two values would be same like this :

`$age=array("Peter"=>43,"Ben"=>43);` .

It should return the key "Peter" and key "Ben" and maybe store the keys in another array The reason is to find if two people are of same age if same age then i would like to do several other things. I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I searched the built in array functions, But couldn't find one that exactly suits my case.

Comment: Always array have two elements only?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh yeah . Only two. No more for some reason. Help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the unique values and see if there is only 1:

```
if(count(array_unique($age)) === 1) {
     return array_keys($age);
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Because I was bored, here are two others.

Assuming only 2 elements:

```
if(($v = array_values($age)) && $v[0] === $v[1]) {
     return array_keys($age);
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Also, should work with multiples:

```
if((array_sum($age) % count($age)) === 0) {
     return array_keys($age);
} else {
     return false;
}
```

Comment: lol, I literally was just writing the same code :) (Just with a ternary)

Comment: @SaifullahAlam This answer is correct. You take all unique values from your array and count them. If it is only 1 element left, then all values are the same and there is only 1 unique value. If this condition is TRUE, then he returns the keys of your array otherwise false

Comment: Oh sorry i tested in a wrong way. Yeah that is really correct.

Comment: @AbraCadaver. Thats really brilliant. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AbraCadaver. You are so brilliant. I also might need the multiple one checking.